# Loads Tags Merger

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[uploads](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/uploads)[file-upload](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/file-upload)[large-file-upload](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/large-file-upload)[fileupload](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fileupload)=>[upload](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/upload)

[downloads](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/downloads)[file-downloads](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/file-downloads)[downloading](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/downloading)[large-file-download](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/large-file-download)=>[download](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/download)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)